# Nginx return file WITH file extension

Tags: nginx

I'm returning a pdf file at a specific location in nginx. When someone goes to `mysite.com/resume`, I want my `resume.pdf` to be returned but at the redirected url of `mysite.com/resume.pdf` (so that the browser will show download/print/etc buttons related to pdfs).

What I have below returns the pdf since `resume.pdf` is in `/dir/to/contents/`, but as `mysite.com/resume`, not `mysite.com/resume.pdf`. How can I achieve this kind of redirect?

```
server {
            listen       80;
            listen       [::]:80;
            server_name  mysite.com;
            root /dir/to/contents;

            location / {
                index site.html;
            }

}
```

-
Edit: address first comment

Comment: From the configuration you show in your question, it's not obvious how you are mapping `/resume` to `/resume.pdf`.

Comment: @RichardSmith - just addressed above, `resume.pdf` is in the dir specified by the `root` directive

Comment: So you just renamed the file from `resume.pdf` to `resume`? Remark the your browser doesn't care if the URL of the page ends in `.pdf`, what matters is the [media type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type) sent by nginx. On the other hand nginx guesses the media type based on the file extension. So what URL do you want to have and what do you want to call the file on the disk? I assume you want the content served as `application/pdf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both edo1 and Danila Vershinin's answers will return the pdf, but both return it at the url without the `.pdf` ending - for my picky use case of wanting the file returned with the `.pdf` extension I found the directive below to work.

```
server {
    ...
    rewrite ^/resume$ resume.pdf redirect;
    ...
}
```

Not sure if this offers worse performance than other answers or if it's not as idiomatic, but it does what I was looking for. The `redirect` at the end returns a 302.

Answer (score 1):

Add `.pdf` to `/resume` (invisible to the client):

```
    rewrite ^(/resume)$ $1.pdf last;
```

It is good idea to provide correct file name to the browser, e.g.

```
    location ~* ([^/]*\.pdf)$ {
        add_header Content-Disposition 'attachment; filename="$1"';
    }
```

Comment: thanks, please see comment on Danila Vershinin's post - tried your code in the same way and couldn't get it to work

Comment: rewrite rule should be in `location /` block or in `server` block.

Answer (score 0):

The following should be sufficient (I did test this):

```
rewrite ^/resume$ /resume.pdf last;
```

As pointed out by @Piotr P. Karwasz the MIME type detection will be handled by NGINX. Because the rewrite ends up with a `.pdf` file, NGINX will correctly serve it as `application/pdf`.

The extra bits by @edo1 are only needed in case you prefer to have the file to be prompted for downloaded, as opposed to default behavior of your browser (many - displays in browser).

Comment: thanks for your resp. What version/environment did you test it out in? I'm trying it on Ubuntu nginx 1.14.0 with `localhost` as `server_name` and can't get it to work. Tried putting the above directive in the `server` block, in the `location /` block, and in a `location /resume /` block, and none work for me.

Comment: The environment where I got this to work is CentOS 7 / NGINX 1.16.x stable. However, it's not environment specific. Make sure it's put in `server { }` context directly (outside of any `location`)